# Whats the correct way to implement an activity to manage other activities

Tags: android

I am working on a android app that does the following:
using a viewpager, you first see names and image of faces, then you need to select the correct name per face.

in the first activity (A) you swipe through names and faces,
and in the next activity (B) you see a face and need to select the corresponding name.

At the moment i show 4 faces.
I want to expand it so i have a list of 28 faces and then show and quiz only 4 each time tracking the result.

my problem is, I handle the list of faces in activity A, once i go to activity B activity A dies and so does the list of faces.
is there a correct design in order to manage the list?
can i create a blank activity to manage other activities?

an option i have is after activity B finishes pass all need information in an intent and start a new activity A, but that seems not right.

hope i made myself clear.
thanks in advance.

Comment: **once i go to activity B activity A dies and so does the list of faces.** during activity navigation you have 2 choice either finish the activity or save instance of activity if you have some dependency on background activity. or make base activity with some useful method so you can access all over the app.

Answer (score 0):

Before I state my opinion, I want to ask: Activity A should not died even you start Activity B, how did you do that?

Back on your question, these are basic ideas and already has many solution on the internet so I'll provide keywords and the document for you to find them.

**Bring data from A to B :**

You can pass your data by `Bundle`, the basic way is transform your list into `String` type and transform it back in B. The keywords of this is `Bundle` and `intent.putExtra(bundle)` : [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#putExtras(android.content.Intent))

**Handling [data returns from B] in A :**

You can call `startActivityForResult(B)` to start `B` and wait for its result in `A`, the keyword is startActivityForResult : [document](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#StartActivity)

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. The issue is that i need to restart activity A, set new layout each time. so i dont see how startActivityForResult could help. and i closed activity A with "finish()"